# Unable to lock rotation for one view controller in IOS10

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, ios10, swift5

**Background**

I have an app that uses AVFoundation in order to have a custom camera. This happens in the `OCRViewController`. When I take a picture I send the captured picture to a different view `ImagePreviewViewController`.

I am using `Xcode 10.2.1 (10E1001)` with `Swift 5`

**The Goal**

What I would like to achieve is to lock the orientation of the `ImagePreviewViewController` to the original orientation of the image. I already know how to get the orientation of the image but I am not able to lock the orientation of the view.

I get the image rotation as such: `let imageOri = capturedImage?.imageOrientation`

**What did I try?**

I tried the accepted answers at and several other sources:

[How to lock orientation just for one view controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29950456/how-to-lock-orientation-just-for-one-view-controller)

[How to lock orientation of one view controller to portrait mode only in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28938660/how-to-lock-orientation-of-one-view-controller-to-portrait-mode-only-in-swift)

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-lock-a-view-controllers-orientation-using-supportedinterfaceorientations

Reading the documentation at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/supportedInterfaceOrientations under *Handling View Rotation* the following is stated:

I also tried the many suggested solutions while writing this query, however, the majority appears to use the following approach (or a variation of it), and it does not work for me.

```swift
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
    return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait.rawValue)
}

override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool{
    return false
}

override func preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation() -> UIInterfaceOrientation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait
}
```

> As of iOS 8, all rotation-related methods are deprecated. Instead, rotations are treated as a change in the size of the view controller’s view and are therefore reported using the viewWillTransition(to:with:) method.

However, I am not sure how to progress from here.

**Interesting code snippets**

The following method is in my `OCRViewController`, here I instantiate the `ImagePreviewViewController` and attach the captured image.

```swift
func displayCapturedPhoto(capturedPhoto : UIImage) {
    let imagePreviewViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ImagePreviewViewController") as! ImagePreviewViewController
    imagePreviewViewController.capturedImage = capturedPhoto
    navigationController?.pushViewController(imagePreviewViewController, animated: true)
}
```

Using the below override function inside my `ImagePreviewViewController` I am able to detect the orientation of the view controller.

```swift
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
        print("Landscape")
    } else {
        print("Portrait")
    }
}
```

Comment: What i did was in `UIApplicationDelegate` . declare two variables `var shouldSupportAllOrientation = true` and `var orientationLock = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait`  and using supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor in appDelegate return the orientationLock variable. in your viewcontroller `appDelegate?.shouldSupportAllOrientation = true` `appDelegate?.orientationLock = .portrait`

Comment: @KamalUpasena I just tried that and it sadly does not work. I did it likewise: in my AppDelegate I made the two variables as you specified. Then in my view controller under viewWillAppear (also tried viewDidLoad) I used it as you do, and the view still rotates regardless of the extra code.

Comment: Add Orientation support for 4 items in info.plist

Comment: @KamalUpasena can you elaborate? I am not sure I understand what these 4 items are.

Comment: Add Device Orientation as Portrait, Upside Down, Landscape Left, Landscape Right from the General -> Deployment Info

Comment: Ah, that I have already checked for all Device Orientations. The issue is related to the ViewController in which i display my image rotates regardless of what I have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To restrict the rotation of one screen, use this.

In AppDelegate

```
var restrictRotation = Bool()

func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if !restrictRotation {
        return .portrait
    } else {
        return .all
    }
}
```

In your viewcontroller add the function,

```
func restrictRotation(restrict : Bool) -> Void {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
    appDelegate?.restrictRotation = restrict
}
```

In the ViewDidload() method, call the function to disable rotation.

```
    self.restrictRotation(restrict: false)
```

in viewWillDisappear() method, call the function to enable rotation.

```
    self.restrictRotation(restrict: true)
```

Comment: Hey. I have tried your solution and sadly it does not work for my case. There are no errors or anything. It simply rotates regardless of the code.

Comment: in my case, it is working fine. Which is device OS version.

Comment: It is an iPad pro, version 12.3.1.

Comment: it is working correctly in iPhone 8 12.3.1. I update the answer. Please check that. Call that function inside **viewDidload()**

Comment: Hmm, no luck for me yet. I think there might be some setup configuration which is causing this issue. I tried your solution on a test app and it works. I will mark it as correct answer.