# Can't force rotate of orientation in landscape mode

Tags: ios, uikit, device-orientation

My entire app is portrait mode. However, one screen needs to be able to rotate to landscape (for playing video). I am able to enable all orientation rotations with no problem [via @Jonathan Danek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59634088/3814160).

In my AppDelegate I have:

```
static var orientationLock = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
```

and subsequently:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return AppDelegate.orientationLock
}
```

So to enable rotation for all orientations, I do the following as the video view-controller is presented:

```
AppDelegate.orientationLock = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.all
UINavigationController.attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation()
```

This works great  ..the problem is when I try to *change it back* to only portrait mode.

I am trying this as the video view-controller is dismissed:

```
AppDelegate.orientationLock = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
UINavigationController.attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation()
```

..but it does not trigger the above AppDelegate's **supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow** function if the video view-controller is currently rotated to Landscape. What's interesting is that it *will* trigger the function if the video view-controller is currently rotated to Portrait.

So I'm wondering how I can set my one view-controller to have *all* orientations, but then change it back to just portrait?

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45351231/2781088 if the answer is helpful.

Comment: I solved this by going the route [@bmjohns answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28938660/how-to-lock-orientation-of-one-view-controller-to-portrait-mode-only-in-swift)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to overwrite `supportedInterfaceOrientations` in your controller? That might help.

Example:

```
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.all
}
```

> Returns all of the interface orientations that the view controller supports.

[Apple Doc - supportedInterfaceOrientations](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621435-supportedinterfaceorientations)

**Swift 5.1 short version:**

```
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    .all
}
```