# Lock orientation in single Swift VC with Objective C AppDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I've got an Objetive-C app delegate that is part of a project I'm interfacing with my own. I'm attempting to lock orientation, but it looks like the old methods (below) no longer work. Setting the orientation in `viewDidLoad` rotates the screen but allows the user to rotate back to `portrait`. I've attempted converting to `"override var"` but no luck. The current solutions (link below) look to all involve an `app delegate` call, but I cannot locate the solution for a Swift call to an `Objective C` app delegate.

[How to lock orientation of one view controller to portrait mode only in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28938660/how-to-lock-orientation-of-one-view-controller-to-portrait-mode-only-in-swift)

```
 override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return false
 }

 override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.landscapeRight
 }
```

Comment: The supported interface orientations is a variable in Swift, not a method.
https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621435-supportedinterfaceorientations

Comment: As noted above, I changed "func" to "var", it doesn't seem to impact it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem using this link, after trying just about everything.
[how to lock portrait orientation for only main view using swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25606442/how-to-lock-portrait-orientation-for-only-main-view-using-swift)

I utilized the answer from JasonJasonJason and updated the code to get rid of the ->.

The below code went in my first VC

```
extension UINavigationController {
override open var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return true
}

override open var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return (visibleViewController?.supportedInterfaceOrientations)!
}
}
```

Then subsequent VCs

```
    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.landscape
}
```

Then since I had a TabBarController, I added this to the controller that pushes to the tab view. If you try to re-use the initial UINavigationController extension it won't let you, but the TabBarController ignores it. So the below extension solves it for any VC's with the TabBar

```
extension UITabBarController {
override open var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return true
}

override open var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.landscape
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To force only one controller to be at landscape orientation.
Manager:

```
class OrientationManager {

    static let shared = OrientationManager()

    /// you can set any orientation to lock
    var orientationLock = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait

    /// lock orientation and force to rotate device
    func lock(for orientation: UIInterfaceOrientationMask, rotateTo rotateOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {
        orientationLock = orientation
        UIDevice.current.setValue(rotateOrientation.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
    }
}
```

Usage:

1) Add code to AppDelegate

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return OrientationManager.shared.orientationLock
}
```

2) Use in controller

```
open class LandscapeController: UIViewController {

    /// orientation for one controller
    override open func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        OrientationManager.shared.lock(for: .landscape, rotateTo: .landscapeLeft)
    }

    /// set previous state of orientation or any new one
    override open func viewWillDisappear(_ animated : Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        OrientationManager.shared.lock(for: .portrait, rotateTo: .portrait)
    }
}
```

Comment: @rtnlsltn What do you mean "Obj-C" ? There is not difference between swift and obj-c

Answer (score 0):

**For xcode 8.x & swift 3.x**

We can control device orientation for particular screen. 
On **AppDelegate.swift** make a variable `enableAllOrientation`:

```
var enableAllOrientation = false

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        if (enableAllOrientation == true){
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.all
        }
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
    }
```

& mask for particular view controller as -

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
    {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.enableAllOrientation = false
    }
```

Comment: I have an objective-c app delegate with a bridging header, how would I utilize this?

Comment: @rtnlsltn Use a protocol. Make your AppDelegate conform to it.